# Edit Page -> Loading A Blank White Page

Tags: php, forms, codeigniter

I have an issue when I click on a link to edit a sale `http://domain/admin/editsale/index/21/sale-name`  I seem to get a blank page loaded so I have a feeling that it is not getting the `$id` but I cannot spot my issue.

**Controller:**

```
if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');

class Editsale extends CI_Controller {

    function __construct() {
    parent::__construct();

    }

    function index($id) {
        if(!$this->session->userdata('logged_in'))redirect('admin/home');

        if($this->input->post('submit')) {

            #Set The Validation Rules
                $this->form_validation->set_rules('name', 'Name', 'trim|required');
                $this->form_validation->set_rules('location', 'Location', 'trim|required');
                $this->form_validation->set_rules('bedrooms', 'Bedrooms', 'trim|is_natural');
                $this->form_validation->set_rules('bathrooms', 'Bathrooms', 'trim');
                $this->form_validation->set_rules('condition', 'Condition', 'trim');
                $this->form_validation->set_rules('description', 'Description', 'trim');
                $this->form_validation->set_rules('price', 'Price', 'trim');

            if($this->form_validation->run() == FALSE) {

                #Set the $data for the view if FALSE
                $data['cms_pages'] = $this->navigation_model->getCMSPages($id);
                $data['sales_pages'] = $this->sales_model->getSalesPages($id);
                $data['sale'] = $this->sales_model->getSalesContent($id);
                $data['content'] = $this->load->view('admin/editsale', $data, TRUE); #Loads the "content"

                $this->load->view('admintemplate', $data); #Loads the given template and passes the $data['content'] into it
            }

            #Form Validation Was Correct So Lets Continue 

            #Lets Set What We Are Sending To The DB
                    $content = array(
                    'name' => $this->input->post('name', TRUE),
                    'location' => $this->input->post('location', TRUE),
                    'bedrooms' => $this->input->post('bedrooms', TRUE),
                    'bathrooms' => $this->input->post('bathrooms', TRUE),
                    'condition' => $this->input->post('condition', TRUE),
                    'description' => $this->input->post('description', TRUE),
                    'price' => $this->input->post('price', TRUE)
                    );

                    if($this->sales_model->updateSale($id, $content)) {
                            $data['success'] = TRUE; #displays sale updated
                            $data['cms_pages'] = $this->navigation_model->getCMSPages($id);
                            $data['sales_pages'] = $this->sales_model->getSalesPages($id);
                            $data['sale'] = $this->sales_model->getSalesContent($id);
                            $data['content'] = $this->load->view('admin/editsale', $data, TRUE); #Loads the "content"
                } // Sale Update End
                    }else{ 
                $data['cms_pages'] = $this->navigation_model->getCMSPages($id);
                $data['sales_pages'] = $this->sales_model->getSalesPages($id);
                $data['sale'] = $this->sales_model->getSalesContent($id);
                $data['content'] = $this->load->view('admin/editsale', $data, TRUE); #Loads the "content"
                }#Submit End    
        } #Index End
}
```

**Model:**

```
function getSalesPages($id = NULL) {
    $query = $this->db->get('sales');
    if($query->num_rows() > 0) return $query->result();

}

function getSalesContent($id = NULL) {
    $this->db->where('id', $id);
    $query = $this->db->get('sales', 1);

    if($query->num_rows() > 0) {
        $row = $query->result_array();
        return $row;
    }else{
        return FALSE;
    }
}
```

**View:**

```
<?php
//Setting form attributes
$formEditSale = array('id' => 'editSale', 'name' => 'editSale');
$formName = array('id' => 'name', 'name' => 'name');
$formLocation = array('id' => 'location', 'name' => 'location');
$formBedrooms = array('id' => 'bedrooms','name' => 'bedrooms');
$formBathrooms = array('id' => 'bathrooms','name' => 'bathrooms');
$formCondition = array('id' => 'condition','name' => 'condition');
$formDescription = array('id' => 'description','name' => 'description');
$formPrice = array('id' => 'price','name' => 'price');

if($success == TRUE) {
echo '<section id = "validation">Sale Updated</section>';   
}
?>

?>

<section id = "validation"><?php echo validation_errors();?></section>

<?php
echo form_open_multipart('admin/editsale/index/'.$sale[0]['id'].'/'.url_title($sale[0]['name'],'dash', TRUE),$formEditSale);
echo form_fieldset();
echo form_label('Name:', 'name');
echo form_input($formName, $sale[0]['name']);
echo form_label ('Location', 'location');
echo form_input($formLocation, $sale[0]['location']);
echo form_label ('Bedrooms', 'bedrooms');
echo form_input($formBedrooms, $sale[0]['bedrooms']);
echo form_label ('Bathrooms', 'bathrooms');
echo form_input($formBathrooms, $sale[0]['bathrooms']);
echo form_label ('Condition', 'condition');
echo form_input($formCondition, $sale[0]['condition']);
echo form_label ('Price', 'price');
echo form_input($formPrice, $sale[0]['sale']);
echo form_label ('Description', 'description');
echo form_textarea($formDescription, $sale[0]['description']);
echo form_submit('submit','Submit');
echo form_fieldset_close();
echo form_close();
```

Comment: Is your `display_errors` set to off? WIth PHP, if there's any fatal errors during script startup, and display_errors is off, then all you get is that white screen. Check your server's error log for more details.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed,  I was loading the view before the data